# Does VPN on a virtual machine make the host connection VPN as well?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, vpn

I am using VPN on a virtual machine to my organization's network. And I was just wondering whether this will make the host connection also under VPN.

My organization's network may be monitored for various reasons. So, will my host be in my organization's network as well?

The VM is with Oracle VirtualBox 5.x, Linux on windows host, and the network setting is NAT.

Comment: No, it won't effect your host machine's network connection based on what you said (which isn't a lot of details), unless you are using an extremely unusual network setup between your VM and host

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I was just wondering whether this will make the host connection also under VPN.

No, it will not. But let's take a moment to discuss different network types for VirtualBox and how it effects VM network structure.

If you configure your VM to use NAT to access the network then your traffic from your VM will be translated to your host's IP address using the VirtualBox driver before it get's to your first upstream network device (i.e. switch). This results in traffic from your VM being seen by your network as coming from your host's IP address.

If you configure your VM to use Bridged to access the network then your traffic from your VM goes from it through your host's psychical network adapter without being translated so your network sees the traffic as coming from the VM's IP address instead of the host's IP address.

So it is actually possible for you to run multiple VirtualBox VMs on your host each configured as Bridged and each connected to different VPN servers without your host being connected to either of them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just looked at "what's my ip" on google on both the host and the VM. And the IP seems to be the same when the VM is on VPN? Does this mean both are on VPN.

Comment: What type of VPN are you using? Is your web traffic tunneling through the VPN and then going to your destination? It sounds like you are trying to use your VPN as a web proxy.

Try this, disconnect from the VPN and then open your web browser and go to ipchicken.com from both your VM and your host. Write down your public IP address. Then open your VM and connect to your VPN from the VM. Open your web browser on both your VM and the host again. Are the IP addresses the same? Are they different from what they were before you connected the VM to the VPN?

Comment: Been hunting for a concise answer like this a while. Thanks!